# How to upload image to server using web api?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am at learning phase of web api and I want to upload image to server using web api in mvc dot net. I have tried much but not getting solution.

In controller I have done this.

```
string img = username + "_" + labTestId + fb;
var element2 = image;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(element2));
byte[] imagesbytes = ms.ToArray();
string folder_name = "lab-orders";
folder_name = folder_name.ToLower();
string SaveLocation = ServerConfig.BlobPath + folder_name + "/" + fb+imagesbytes;
BlobUploader.UploadTo(folder_name,img, ms);

//   var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Userimage/" + postedFile.FileName + extension);
var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(SaveLocation + postedFile.FileName + extension);

postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
```

How can I upload image to server using web api?

Comment: Can you shere whole action?
Where are You trying to uploafd image? To azure blob storage?

Comment: yes to azure blob storrage i want to upload using web api

Answer (score 1):

It's not that simple.

In this [tutorial](https://ppolyzos.com/2016/02/07/upload-a-file-to-azure-blob-storage-using-web-api/) You have step by step everything You have to do, to upload image.

In brief:

1. Create Blob Storage Account, and get access keys.
2. Save keys in Your web config.
3. Install WindowsAzureStorage from nuget packege manager
        Create blob storage client, get or create blob container
4. create CloudBlockBlob and upload it.

**Edit**
Change link to web api tutorial insted of mvc tutorial

Comment: If this answer helped You, please mark it as such if it was helpful using the checkbox next to it @SoftwareStudent